# Bitwise operation to a List<bool>

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a `List<bool>` and want to bitwise XOR the list (to create check bits)

here is what I have currently

```
List<bool> bList = new List<bool>(){true,false,true,true,true,false,false};
bool bResult = bList[0];

for( int i = 1;i< bList.Count;i++)
{
    bResult ^= bList[i];
}
```

Q: Is there a `Linq` one-liner to solve this more elegant?

Comment: this will generate wrong result -> the list starts at index `0` but you do in your loop `1`

Comment: @M.Schena that's because the 0th element is used as start.

Comment: @RenéVogt ok your right, thx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
bool bResult = bList.Aggregate((a, b) => a ^ b);
```

Answer (score 7):

Another one line solution (in addition to *Buh Buh*'s one):

```
bool bResult = bList.Count(a => a) % 2 == 1;
```

when you *xor* a sequence of `bool` you actually want to return `true` if there're *odd* number of `true`s in the sequence

Comment: @berkser: Yes `Aggregate` is much easier to read, but `Count` if often useful when you don't have `Aggregate` analogue e.g. in SQL

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Aggregate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate):

```
bool result = bList.Aggregate((res, b) => res ^ b);
```

This calls the lambda for every element except the first. `res` is the accumulated value (or the *first* element for the first call) and `b` the current value from the list.

Comment: Thanks for explaining when the lambda is called and what is passed to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
         List<bool> bList = new List<bool>() { true, false, true, true, true, false, false };
        bool bResult = bList[0];

        //for (int i = 1; i < bList.Count; i++)
        //{
        //    bResult ^= bList[i];
        //}
        bList.ForEach(t=>bResult ^= t);
```

Comment: This would xor the first element twice, leading to a different result than in the question. (and btw: List<T>.ForEach is not part of Linq).

Comment: this answer gives a invalid result